# Images are not showing in mail clients

Tags: css, email, attachment

Hello everyone,
                 I m working on a newsletter, It is running fine in browsers(Even in IE9) but in mail clients like outlook, window live mail it is not showing the images which are used as a background using CSS.

Comment: Host them somewhere and absolute link them.

Comment: Without seeing any of the HTML or CSS, it's very difficult to give a definite answer. dotty's answer seems like the most sensible solution at this point, though.

Comment: Give direct URL path to image rather than relative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS support in email clients varies wildly: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. This is why some companies charge more for converting email designs to HTML than converting a full website design. As a first-hand witness (converted more than one email designs into HTML) I'd absolutely recommend using a template:

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/
- http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/

Comment: Thank you so much Halil ,I was wondering for solution of this problem from last 3 days and u just solve within a minute.

Comment: Np and hope to see your appreciation in other forms ;)